# How to record and play sound in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios4, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

I tried using `AVAudioSession` and `AVAudioPlayer` to record and play sounds respectively but the sound volume is very low.

I tried putting volume value of `AVAudioPlayer` to 1.0 and more but didn't help much.

What could be my other options to record sound which can be loud enough to play back?

Comment: Are you using the built-in microphone, or the mic that's on the cord of the standard earbuds?  How close is the source of the sound to the mic?  What kind of values are you seeing if you log -peakPowerForChannel?

Comment: @NSResponder: I am using built-in microphone. Also can you explain how to log -peakPowerForChannel?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This code should be useful for you:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>

    UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;                
    AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,          
                                 sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);
```

It will increase volume.  The functionality of the code is to convert the ordinary sound to speaker sound on ur iPhone. That's why kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker is used.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will check it out and get back to you soon :)

Comment: Thanks a lot this did work :) I was in search of a solution to this since a day now.

Comment: Don't forget the import statement. Perhaps obvious for the more experienced programmers...

#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>

Comment: I added that to the answer above, thanks for mentioning the import required.

Comment: I got it to work (the sounds comes out of the speakers), but I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly.  Is this a one-time thing at app-launch?  Once at viewDidLoad for my controller?  Once every time I make a new AVAudioPlayer?  As KKendal asked: where does this go?  Thanks!

Comment: Your code works just fine :) but it is now deprecated since iOS7. Please see my answer below for an updated solution.

Answer (score 23):

Since iOS7 you can fix this issue directly with AVAudioSession

The overrideOutputAudioPort method does the same than AudioSessionSetProperty

```
NSError *setOverrideError;
NSError *setCategoryError;

AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&setCategoryError];

if(setCategoryError){
    NSLog(@"%@", [setCategoryError description]);
}

[session overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:&setOverrideError];


if(setOverrideError){
    NSLog(@"%@", [setOverrideError description]);
}
```

Comment: this line saved my life, thanks man 
[session overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:&setOverrideError];

Answer (score 4):

Swift version :

```
 import AVFoundation
 var overrideError : NSError?
    if AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(.Speaker, error: &error){

    }else{
        print("error in overrideOutputAudioPort " + overrideError!.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Swift 2:

```
        do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.Speaker)
        } catch {
        }
```

Comment: With Swift 2, this is now a do-try-catch situation, no need for overrideError optional

Answer (score 1):

The following code fixed this issue for me:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
UInt32 doChangeDefault = 1;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker, sizeof(doChangeDefault), &doChangeDefault);
```

Answer (score 0):

MAN, try this.

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
if (![session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
              withOptions:kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker
                    error:&setCategoryError]) {
        // handle error
}

NSError *error;
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.playlet.urlSound];

self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data fileTypeHint:@"aac" error:&error];

self.audioPlayer.delegate = self;

if (error)
    NSLog(@"Error: %@",
          [error localizedDescription]);
else
    [_audioPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

just set this 
[session overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:&setOverrideError];
It works for me.